# Copy .html() of a div and pass it as the title attribute for an <a> tag via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, title

So basically I have "Jack Shephard" under 'div.actor-name a' & I want that same value to be the title attribute for 'div.actor-image a'. Same thing for "John Lock" as well, so multiple cases.

JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
var actortitle = $("div.actor-image a").closest.('div.actor-name a').html();

$("div.actor-image a").each(function() {
$(this).attr('title', actortitle );
});
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="actor1" class="lost">

<div class="actor-name">
<a href="http://www.lost.com">
Jack Shephard
</a>
</div>

<div class="actor-roles">
ROLES GO HERE
</div>

<div class="actor-image">
<a title="Jack Shephard" id="actor1-image" src="jack.jpg" href="http://www.lost.com"></a>
</div>

</div>



<div id="actor2" class="lost">

<div class="actor-name">
<a href="http://www.lost.com">
John Lock
</a>
</div>

<div class="actor-roles">
ROLES GO HERE
</div>

<div class="actor-image">
<a title="John Lock" id="actor2-image" src="john.jpg" href="http://www.lost.com"></a>
</div>

</div>
```

The current jQuery isn't working as expected and is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("div.actor-image a").attr('title', function(i,val) {
    var text = $(this).parent().prevAll('.actor-name').text();
    return $.trim( text );
});
```

This uses the [`attr()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method, but passes it a function. The return value of the function will be the new value.

In the function, it uses the [`parent()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method to traverse to the parent of the `<a>`, then the [`prevAll()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) method to get the `.actor-name` element, then the [`text()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method to grab its text content.

Before it returns the text, it uses the [`jQuery.trim()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) method to trim any leading or trailing whitespace from the text.

Comment: Thank you patrick, works like a charm and very helpful answer. I was wondering, what the (i,val) in function's purpose is?

Comment: @Moving Gifts: Good question. I didn't use them in this answer, but `i` is the index of the current element (since this will be applied to each element that was found). And the `val` is the current value of the `title`  attribute (if any).